# Replace every alpha character with itself + wildcard in string SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

My goal is to create a query that will search for results related to a specific keyword.

Say in a database we had the word cat.

Regardless of if the user types C a t, C.A.T. or Cat I want to find a result related to the search as long as the alpha numeric characters are in the correct sequence that is all that matters

Say in the database we have these 4 records

```
cat
c/a/t
c.a.t
c. at
```

If the user types in `C#$*(&A   T` I'd like to get all 4 results.

What I have written so far in my query is a function that strips any non-alphanumeric characters from the input string.

What can I do to replace each alphanumeric character with itself and add a wildcard at the end?

For every alpha character my input would look similar to this

```
C%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%A%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%T%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that search string will return only one record from this table: the row with `'c.a.t '`.

This is because the expression `C%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%A` does not mean there can't be any alpha-numeric chars between `C` and `A`.
What it actually means is there should be at least one non alpha-numeric value between `C` and `A`.

Moreover, it will return incorrect values as well - a value like `'c u a s e t '` will be returned.

You need to change your where clause to something like this:

```
WHERE column LIKE '%C%A%T%'
AND column NOT LIKE '%C%[a-zA-Z0-9]%A%[a-zA-Z0-9]%T%'
```

This way, if you have `cat` in the correct order, the first row will resolve to `true`, and if there are no other alpha-numeric chars between `c`, `a`, and `t` the second row will resolve to `true`.

Here is a test script, where you can see for yourself what I mean:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    a varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('cat'),
('c/a/t'),
('c.a.t '),
('c. at'),
('c u a s e t ')

-- Incorrect where clause
SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE a LIKE 'C%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%A%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%T%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'

-- correct where clause
SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE a LIKE '%C%A%T%'
AND a NOT LIKE '%C%[a-zA-Z0-9]%A%[a-zA-Z0-9]%T%'
```

You can also see it in action in [this link](http://rextester.com/GDYO28985).

And since I had some spare time, here is a script to create both the `like` and the `not like` patterns from the input string:

```
DECLARE @INPUT varchar(100) = '@*# c %^&# a ^&*$&* t (*&(%!@#$'

DECLARE @Index int = 1,
        @CurrentChar char(1), 
        @Like varchar(100),
        @NotLike varchar(100) = '%'

WHILE @Index < LEN(@Input) 
BEGIN

    SET @CurrentChar = SUBSTRING(@INPUT, @Index, 1)

    IF PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%', @CurrentChar) = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @NotLike = @NotLike + @CurrentChar + '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'
    END
    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

SELECT  @NotLike = LEFT(@NotLike, LEN(@NotLike) - 12),
        @Like = REPLACE(@NotLike, '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', '%')


SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE a LIKE @Like
AND a NOT LIKE @NotLike
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively go through your (cleaned) search string and to each letter add the expression you would like. In my example @builtString should be what you would like to use further on, if I understood correctly.

```sql
declare @cleanSearch as nvarchar(10) = 'CAT'
declare @builtString as nvarchar(100) = ''

WHILE LEN(@cleanSearch) > 0 -- loop until you deplete the search string
    BEGIN
        SET @builtString = @builtString + substring(@cleanSearch,1,1) + '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'  -- append the letter plus regular expression
            SET @cleanSearch = right(@cleanSearch, len(@cleanSearch) - 1)               -- remove first letter of the search string
    END

SELECT @builtString --will look like C%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%A%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%T%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%
SELECT @cleanSearch --@cleanSearch is now empty
```